# Select a column from one tbl and insert into another column in an other table

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my Query?
I have two tables event and customer, I want to select customer id from customer table and insert it in the customer_id Column in the event table. this is only where the login id in the customers table is the same as the logged in user id

```
$insEvent_sql = "INSERT INTO event(customer_id, videography_package, event_type, event_shortdesc, event_vanue, event_start) 
VALUES(customer-id,'".$safe_videography_package."', '".$safe_event_type."', '".$safe_event_shortdesc."','".$safe_event_vanue."',  '".$event_date."') SELECT customer_id  FROM 'customer' WHERE login_id = ".$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID'].";";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `INSERT` a row followed by a `SELECT`. A work around is to add your row to the `SELECT`:

```
$insEvent_sql = "INSERT INTO event 
            (customer_id, 
             videography_package, 
             event_type, 
             event_shortdesc, 
             event_vanue, 
             event_start) 
SELECT 'customer-id'                        AS customer_id, 
       '" . $safe_videography_package . "'  AS videography_package, 
       '" . $safe_event_type . "'           AS event_type, 
       '" . $safe_event_shortdesc . "'      AS event_shortdesc, 
       '" . $safe_event_vanue . "'          AS event_venu, 
       '" . $event_date . "'        AS event_start 
UNION ALL 
SELECT customer_id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM   customer 
WHERE  login_id = " . $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID'];
```

Using sample data:

```
$safe_videography_package = 'package1';
$safe_event_type = 'type1';
$safe_event_shortdesc = 'short description';
$safe_event_vanue = 'some venu';
$event_date = '2012-05-05';
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID'] = 1;
```

Will produce:

```
INSERT INTO event 
            (customer_id, 
             videography_package, 
             event_type, 
             event_shortdesc, 
             event_vanue, 
             event_start) 
SELECT 'customer-id'       AS customer_id, 
       'package1'          AS videography_package, 
       'type1'             AS event_type, 
       'short description' AS event_shortdesc, 
       'some venu'         AS event_venu, 
       '2012-05-05'        AS event_start 
UNION ALL 
SELECT customer_id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
FROM   customer 
WHERE  login_id = 1
```

Comment: You can't make a `UNION` with subqueries with different number of columns.

Comment: @BillKarwin Forgot about that. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, It solved the error I was getting but I have this error " The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns" eventhough the columns are correct

Comment: @SalimShari Just make sure you saw the update with the `NULL`s

Comment: that is giving me an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' AS event_type, 'gggggggg' AS event_shortdesc, ' at line 6"

Comment: @SalimShari Sorry, missed a quote.

Comment: I got it Thanks it is doing what I wanted it to do, the query is inserting the customer id correctly, but not the event details it inserts NULL NULL instead. I appreciate your help thanks

Comment: The following works for me but it doesn't insert the customer_id. Can anyone help me on tha. Thanks $insEvent_sql = "INSERT INTO event(customer_id,videography_package,event_type,event_shortdesc,event_vanue,eve‌​nt_start) SELECT 'customer_id' AS customer_id, '" . $safe_videography_package . "' AS videography_package, '" . $safe_event_type . "' AS event_type, '" . $safe_event_shortdesc . "' AS event_shortdesc, '" . $safe_event_vanue . "' AS event_venu, '" . $event_date . "' AS event_start FROM customer WHERE login_id = " . $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID'];

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   $insEvent_sql = "INSERT INTO event(customer_id, videography_package, event_type, event_shortdesc, event_vanue, event_start) 
   VALUES((select customer-id from 'customer' WHERE login_id = ".$_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID']."),'".$safe_videography_package."', '".$safe_event_type."', '".$safe_event_shortdesc."','".$safe_event_vanue."',  '".$event_date."') ";
```

Comment: The following works for me but it doesn't insert the customer_id. Can anyone help me on tha. Thanks   $insEvent_sql = "INSERT INTO event(customer_id,videography_package,event_type,event_shortdesc,event_vanue,event_start) SELECT 'customer_id' AS customer_id, '" . $safe_videography_package . "' AS videography_package, '" . $safe_event_type . "' AS event_type, '" . $safe_event_shortdesc . "' AS event_shortdesc, '" . $safe_event_vanue . "' AS event_venu, '" . $event_date . "' AS event_start FROM customer WHERE login_id = " . $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID'];

Comment: No luck, My problem is far less easier then this. I just wan to fetch customer_id from customers_table where the login-id = the current logedin id (sessionID) and insert it into events_table along with event details at same time. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

- The syntax for `INSERT` needs either a `VALUES` clause or a `SELECT` as the source of rows, but not both.
- You are using single-quotes for the table name of your `SELECT`, but single-quotes are only for string literals or date literals.
- You aren't using query parameters, so you have ugly code to manage quoted variables.  I assume `$safe_` means that you have escaped the variables, so at least you may have less chance for SQL injection.

I would write the statement with PDO this way:

```
$cust_sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE login_id = :login_id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($cust_sql);
// test if $stmt is false
$result = $stmt->execute(array(":login_id" => $_SESSION['SESS_LOGIN_ID']));
// test if $result is false
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
  $customer_id = $row["customer_id"];
}

$insEvent_sql = "INSERT INTO event(customer_id, videography_package, event_type,
    event_shortdesc, event_vanue, event_start) 
  VALUES (:customer_id, :videographer_package, :event_type, 
   :event_shortdesc, :event_vanue, :event_start)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($cust_sql);
// test if $insEvent_stmt is false
$result = $insEvent_stmt->execute(array(
  ":customer_id"         => $customer_id,
  ":videographer_package"=> $videography_package,
  ":event_type"          => $event_type,
  ":event_shortdesc"     => $event_shortdesc,
  ":event_vanue"         => $event_vanue,
  ":event_start"         => $event_date
));
// test if $result is false
```